# How to detect more than 3 mouse buttons in Java (Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, mouse

Additionally to the regular 3 buttons my mouse has a backward & forward button - how can I detect in Java **if one of these two buttons is pressed**?

Comment: Do these buttons fire MouseEvents like clicking the other buttons? If so, does mouseEvent.getButton() return useful values for these buttons?

Comment: Even if it does return a different value, I would not think they would be reliable since only the constants for 1, 2, and 3 are in the API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
java.awt.MouseInfo.getNumberOfButtons();
```

Taken from [this site](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/java-swing-how-determine-test-number-mouse-buttons/). Since Swing uses AWT under the hood, don't let that `awt` part bother you.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. stephanos doesn't ask how to determine the number of mouse buttons, but rather which one is pressed.

Comment: -1: Not only does this not answer the question, but the `MouseInfo` class is almost completely useless without support for responding to events.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644842/how-can-i-use-the-back-and-forward-mouse-buttons-in-a-swing-application), the ability for Java to detect any mouse button other than right, left, and middle click was added in Java 7.  In all previous versions, you can't. :-(