# Change value when mouse is clicked

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have `JTextfield`.  Now I want to change value when in this component is mouse clicked. For example: score (2 big `JTextField`) and when I click to one of these field it increase the value from 0:0 to 1:0.

Should I implement `MouseListener` or there is some easy way how I can do this?  In mouse listener I need override just one method `mouseClick` and other method will be empty.

And another question:  when should I implement `MouseListener`?  `e.getButton()` return always 1 for left button and 3 for right button?

Comment: for MouseButtons is there maybe difference between Java6 and Java7 please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644842/how-can-i-use-the-back-and-forward-mouse-buttons-in-a-swing-application

Comment: sounds like a horrible user experience: click on the text field and the text of that same field changes ... to what? ... depending on what? ... why?

Comment: it is bussines feature :) it is something like score (2 big JTextField) and when I click to one of these field it increase his value 0:0 to 1:0 for example :)

Comment: Perhaps the answer I gave is not the best way to go about offering this feature to your user.  I think you should mark the question unanswered and give it a further run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I implement MouseListener or there is some easy way how I can do this? In mouse listner I need override just one method mouseClick and other method will be empty.

Use a [`MouseAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html).

> An abstract adapter class for receiving mouse events. The methods in this class are empty. .. Extend this class to create a MouseEvent (including drag and motion events) or/and MouseWheelEvent listener and **override the methods for the events of interest.**

Answer (score 2):

```
Now I want to change value when in this component is mouse clicked
```

[JTextComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) are Focusable, look for [FocusListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html)

Comment: +5  I forgot to point out that the OP was taking the entirely wrong approach to this.  ( The thought got lost in trying to decide which of the 'more than 1' questions I would answer ;).

Comment: depending on the _real_ requirement (which the OP didn't state), this may or may not solve the problem :-) Generally, I advice to stay clear off focus triggers, as they are low-level, may be asynchronous, vary across platforms ... hard to manage

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `MouseListener` on your class is one way to do it, but if you just want to react to clicks, it's easier to use an anonymous class extending [`MouseAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html)

```
textField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // do your thing here
    }
});
```

As for the second question, the API documentation quite nicely documents the [return values of `MouseEvent.getButton()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getButton%28%29).

Comment: *"the API documentation quite nicely documents the return values of MouseEvent.getButton()."* Sure, and in that same documentation, it mentions *"In particular, for a mouse with one, two, or three buttons this method **may** return the following values:"*  (emphasis mine) Note that 'may' implies 'may not', which is a good reason for using the defined constants rather than relying on magic numbers.